# query parameter of impdp

Tags: oracle, import, syntax

I'm trying to import and dmp files into a specific table in my DB.

I'm running this command:

```
impdp '/ as sysdba' directory=exp
dumpfile=exp_01.dmp,exp_02.dmp 
logfile=log_01.log 
table_exists_action=truncate 
parallel=8 
tables=my_user.my_tbl 
query=my_user.my_tbl: "where trunc(sysdate)-730 > to_date(snapshot_month, 'yyyy/mm')
```

It's raise an exception

> LRM-00116: syntax error at ')' following 'yyyy/mm'

This is the correct where clause and I checkd it against the table with a simple query.

I tried to change the double comma to single comma (and adding one to the to_date format) and so on but any change that I did it didn't worked.

In the net there are also several syntax options for the query parameter (double\single commas).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me at last is to add backslashes before the doube commas.

This is the new command:

```
impdp '/ as sysdba' directory=exp
dumpfile=exp_01.dmp,exp_02.dmp 
logfile=log_01.log 
table_exists_action=truncate 
parallel=8 
tables=my_user.my_tbl 
query=my_user.my_tbl:\"where trunc(sysdate)-730 > to_date(snapshot_month, 'yyyy/mm')\"
```

I guess the purpose is to escape the double commas that comming after them for the query will ignore them.

Thanks.